# Apple Wallet - How to add unsigned boarding pass?

Tags: wallet

I have a web app that generates boarding passes.

I am not a member of the iOS Developer Program. And I can't get certificate to sign the boarding pass.

Is there a way to create a link from web app to add unsigned boarding pass to Wallet?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.